# Laravel5.3 bootstrap error

Tags: laravel

my code test.blade.php

```html
<div class="col-lg-10">
    {{ Form::text('movie', ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
 </div>
```

and error is

ErrorException in helpers.php line 519:
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (Vi

Answer (score 2):

Second parameter for [`Form::text()`](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#text) should be a string, but you're trying to pass an array. This will work:

```
{!! Form::text('movie', '', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Comment: anyway why the `!!`  in the brackets?

Comment: @GluServ, in Laravel 5 you should use `{!! !!}` to [display unescaped data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#displaying-data). In Laravel 4.2 [you should use](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates#other-blade-control-structures)  `{{ }}`

Comment: {!! !!} will not escape string while {{ }} does. This means that if you use {{ }} it would show tags as HTML.